# Query on concat string to array using lamda expression

Tags: java, java-8

```
String A = "Sample";
List<String> val;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    val.add(A + i);
}
```

My output will be Sample1, Sample2, Sample3 etc..
May I know how to handle this script in single line using lambda expression

Comment: Just btw, `val` is not initialized in your code.

Comment: Why would "single line" be a relevant goal during programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IntStream with the map operator to do this. Here's how it looks.

```
List<String> val = IntStream.range(0, 5)
    .mapToObj(i -> A + i)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an int stream for that:

```
String A = "Sample";
List<String> val = IntStream.range(0, 5)
                    .mapToObj(i -> A + i)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

List interface isn't functional interface so you can't use lambda here. I'm doing this using stream:-

```
String A = "Sample";
List<String> val = IntStream.range(0, 5)
                            .mapToObj(num -> A.concat(String.valueOf(num)))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you have one method in the interface then only you can perform lambda.